# Pika RabbitMQ Publish from a consumer

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I have a RabbitMQ consumer. I would like to have that consumer do some message processing, simulated by `time.sleep(10)`, then publish a message to a different queue. I know the consumer callback has a channel that in theory could be used to do the publish, but this seems like a bad implementation because if the `basic_publish()` somehow manages for force close the channel, then the consumer dies. What is the best way to handle this?

```
import time
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')

result = channel.queue_declare(queue='original_queue', exclusive=True)

channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs', queue='original_queue')

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    time.sleep(10)
    ch.basic_publish(exchange='logs', routing_key='different_queue', body='hello_world')

channel.basic_consume(
    queue='original_queue', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: "basic_publish() somehow manages for force close the channel", where is the source for this information? Didn't find in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your consumer in a way that it automatically reconnects to the RabbitMQ server if the connection gets closed. Hope this helps(I didn't put much thought on the design part, feel free to suggest some!)

```
import time
import pika

reconnect_on_failure = True


def consumer(connection, channel):

    channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')
    result = channel.queue_declare(queue='original_queue', exclusive=True)
    channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs', queue='original_queue')
    print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        time.sleep(10)
        ch.basic_publish(exchange='logs', routing_key='different_queue', body='hello_world')

    channel.basic_consume(
  queue='original_queue', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    channel.start_consuming()


def get_connection_and_channel():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    return connection, channel


def start(reconnect_on_failure):
    connection, channel = get_connection_and_channel()
    consumer(connection, channel)
    # the if condition will be executed when the consumer's start_consuming loop exists
    if reconnect_on_failure:
        # cleanly close the connection and channel
        if not connection.is_closed():
            connection.close()
        if not channel.is_close():
            channel.close()
        start(reconnect_on_failure)


start(reconnect_on_failure)
```

Comment: retrying the connection fixes the problem, but doesn't really answer why this behavior is observed..